# Kotlin, high-order function trouble

Tags: kotlin

I have the [following HO function](https://github.com/kotlin-graphics/uno-sdk/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/uno/glm/MatrixStack.kt#L248-L253) on `MatrixStack`

```
inline infix fun run(block: MatrixStack.() -> Any): MatrixStack {
    push()
    block()
    pop()
    return this
}
```

And somewhere else, I have a method where I am trying to return the intermediate result calculated in `block()`

```
fun getSphereOrbitPos(modelMatrix: MatrixStack, orbitCenter: Vec3, orbitAxis: Vec3, orbitRadius: Float, orbitAlpha: Float): Vec3 {

    modelMatrix run {

        translate(orbitCenter)
        rotate(orbitAxis, 360.0f * orbitAlpha)

        var offsetDir = orbitAxis cross Vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)
        if (offsetDir.length() < 0.001f)
            offsetDir = orbitAxis cross Vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)

        offsetDir.normalize_()

        translate(offsetDir * orbitRadius)

        // this is what I'd like to return, top() = MatrixStack.top()
        return (top() * Vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)).toVec3()
    }
} // return error
```

if I declare an external variable

```
fun getSphereOrbitPos(..): Vec3 {

    var result =  Vec3()

    modelMatrix run {
        ..
        result = (top() * Vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)).toVec3() // error
    }
```

I get the following error:

> Expected a value of type Any

Is there a way I can obtain what I want by using `MatrixStack.run{ }`? (because the alternative is to manually call `push()`, `block()` and `pop()`)

Comment: I think you can fix it by adding `Unit` after the last line in your lambda. It complains because the `result = ...` assignment is not of type `Any`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a `return` inside `run { }` and this infix function is inlined, then you return from `getSphereOrbitPos` before `pop()` is called, so don't do that.

And the signature of block is `MatrixStack.() -> Any`, so your block has to return something. You are not using the result of `block` inside `run`, so you could change `MatrixStack.() -> Any` to `MatrixStack.() -> Unit` and therefore don't expect any return value from `block`

Another question is, is there a particular reason to return `this` from `run` always?
If you need to return an intermediate value and still call `push()` and `pop()`, you can change your function to

```
infix inline fun <T> run(block: MatrixStack.() -> T): T {
    pop()
    val result = block()
    push()

    return result
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'd like to return `this` from `run` because so I can concatenate different `block()`s in [this way](https://github.com/java-opengl-labs/modern-jogl-examples/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/main/tut07/worldScene.kt#L191), for example. Anyway, I'll try the `-> Unit`

Comment: Then I'd argue to use the name `apply` instead to be consistent with the standard library. `run` in stdlib runs the block on the receiver and returns the result of block. `apply` instead runs the block on the receiver and returns the receiver

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, dude, I'll do it

Comment: Even better, I'll implement both, `run` and `apply` :p